# Override drawable resources in sdk

Tags: android, sdk

I'm working on android SDK library which external application will use as .aar file, in my SDK i have Drawable resources, the thing is some of the customers that use the SDK want to be able to override some of the Drawables with their own resources.
My question is how this can be done, i tried to put in app module drawable with same name as in sdk module but different image, it seems not stable and random, sometimes it use the actual icon from app module sometimes from sdk.
What i do wrong?
Is this can be fixed with gradle flavors?

Answer (score 1):

After some research i find the solution, in you SDK build.gradle file you have to add config

```
defaultConfig{
  ....
  ....
  vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

This will prevent android to create png's from your vector assets

Answer (score 0):

Once I had to do it, and to use my own Theme and Styles I had to recreate the intire layout with same name and same components and making the changes that were necessary